# Perl one liner to increment a value and replace text

Tags: perl

I have a line in some files where only the year differs -- I need to increment the year and replace the preceding text, for example:

```
tdef 12 linear 18Z31dec2012 1mo
```

should become:

```
tdef 12 linear 00Z01jan2013 1mo
```

I have a perl one liner that I can't get to replace the text and increment at the same time. I've tried quite a few combinations, the correct formatting evades me. This increments but of course I lose the text:

```
perl -pe 's/18Z31dec(\d+)/ 1 + $1 /ge'
```

I can't figure how to insert any text on the substitution and retain the incremented year:

```
perl -pe "s/18Z31dec(\d+)/'00Z01jan($1 + 1)'/ge"
```

Outputs this:

```
tdef 12 linear 00Z01jan( + 1) 1mo
```

Comment: What does `18Z` changing to `00Z` signify? Will it always be the case that it changes in that way? I assume you want to search for and replace any date and not just `31dec2012`? You say only the year should be incremented, but it appears you actually incremented the input date by 1 day (or possibly even only 6 hours if `18Z` signifies the time 18:00). It would be helpful if you provided a larger sample of input lines and their expected outcomes.

Comment: This is a control file/template time start indicator for a year of monthly climate variables. 18Zulu is one of the 6-hour data hacks (00, 06, 12, 18). The start time will always be 00Z01Jan, so only the year increments. I was hoping to present my problem without burdening everyone with these details -- the one-liners can get pretty esoteric.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It wasn't clear to me that you only wanted to update lines that matched `18Z31dec`. I incorrectly assumed you were actually trying to add a consistent interval to every date in your file. I'm glad you were provided the answer you needed.

Comment: Note that "one line" does not mean "one statement".  You could compute and store an intermediate result instead of embedding the whole logic into a single substitution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
perl -pe 's/18Z31dec(\d+)/"00Z01jan" . ($1 + 1)/ge'
```

When you use `/e`, the right side of the substitution is a full Perl expression.  So you have to quote literal strings, concatenate them with `.`, etc.

Instead of an expression with concatenation, you could use the somewhat unattractive arbitrary-expression interpolation syntax that's based on scalar dereference; then you don't need `/e`:

```
perl -pe 's/18Z31dec(\d+)/00Z01jan${\($1 + 1)}/g'
```

Same result.

Comment: Thanks Mark! I usually use sed, it's good to know about the right side difference for perl. +1 for the scalar dereference.